# Scaling accurately

Tags: scale

trying to create a simple platform like the one in the distant left.

I extruded a 6000mm by 6000mm plane, then scale the top plane slightly longer to make that top protrusion. However, the scale tool only allows me to enter a factor of 0 - 1. I wish to protrude out to exactly 6500mm. How do I do that?[image]

Comment: can't you just type in "6500" while scaling?

Comment: @Nate: no, I wish there was some way to do that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just type the equation into the *Scale tool* pop-up.
Depending on your model, you might want to keep Z=1 (doesn't matter in my example).

[image]

Comment: Sweet!! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.